# How do you pass an array to PHP from JQUERY and then send an array back to JQUERY from PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

I am trying to pass a single array to a php script processData.php that will then use that data in order to execute a perl script.

I then want to return the results of the perl script back to JQUERY for display.

It looks like when I try to display the data back, the data comes back as a NULL value.

```
JQUERY PAGE:
$('#numDevices').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var test = [];
        var $number = $('#element');
        var value = $number.val();
        var container = $('#main');
        $('.device').remove();
        $('#send').remove();
        for(var i=0; i<value; i++) {
             container.append('<div class="device"><fieldset><legend>Device' + i + '</legend><textarea class="input"  rows="10">Please enter a hostname, followed by the corresponding links.</textarea></fieldset></div>');

        }
        container.append('<input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="submit"/>');
         $('#send').click(function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();

             var device = new Array();
             $('textarea').each(function(index, area) {
                 var $area = $(area).val();
                 device.push($area);
             });

             $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "processData.php",
                 data: "input"+device,
                 cache: false,

                 success: function(data) {
                     alert(data);
                 },
                 error: function() {
                     alert("FAILED");
                 }
             });
         });
    });
```

.....

```
 PHP PAGE:
<?php
$data =$_GET['input'];
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

So as you can see, to test, I am trying to pass an array to php, and then pass it back to JQUERY for display.  I am getting a NULL value when I pass back, so I can only assume I am sending a NULL value.

If more information is needed I will gladly add it.

**UPDATE**

1) I have changed
    `data: "input"+device,` to
    `data: {input: device},`

I can now see the value via var_dump($data);

The problem I am having now is that the data being sent back to JQUERY is NULL.

**SECOND UPDATE**

1) Added: `dataType: "json"`
2) Changed `GET` to `POST`

New Error:
1) Parsererror 
2) unexpected end of input
3) [Object][Object]

Comment: Don't "assume". There are plenty of utilities out there that help you check what's really going on (like Fiddler or Chrome Developer Tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what was wrong.....

PHP version 5.4 was not installed correctly

When I did a php -v it would tell me 5.4.7, however if I did an rpm -qa | grep php it would show me version 5.1.6.

I had to remove the rpm's for 5.6.1 and install the rpm's for 5.3 and it worked.

Thank you all for helping me in solving this!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
var device = $.map($('textarea'), function(el, i) { return el.value; });

$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "processData.php",
     dataType: 'JSON',
     data: {input : device.join('$$')},
     cache: false
}).done(function(json) {
     console.log(json);
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $data = $_GET['input'];
    echo json_encode( explode('$$', $data) );
?>
```

Comment: ahhh ok I think I may be getting closer.  After doing a var_dump I can see the value is no longer null and is array(1){ [0]=> string(61) "The correct value" }

Comment: It seems like the problem I have now is I am guessing this is incorrect? `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: So what does the alert say ?

Comment: alert is empty.  No value at all.

Comment: Then it does'nt fail, you should be using the console to see what you're getting back, and not alerts. Drop the json_encode and see what is returned ?

Comment: When I take away the `json_encoded` portion, the result displayed is "Array".

Comment: That would be PHP's echo function not being able to display an array (you could use print_r ), and json_encode should work just fine. Again, use the console, and set the dataType to json in your ajax function.

Comment: looks like setting the dataType to "json" is now causing it to the error function.

Error I am getting is `parse error` | `unexpected end of input`

Comment: That means malformed JSON, which means the data returned from PHP is'nt valid JSON.

Comment: is there any reason why it wouldnt be valid json with the following? 

`$data =$_POST['input'];

print_r json_encoded($data);`

Comment: I edited my answer, try that instead. And make sure everything is saved in UTF-8.

Comment: Ok I have implemented your version of it and I am not getting any response back.  Nothing from the logs in chrome unless I am looking at the wrong logs.

Comment: You're echoing something else, or you did'nt save the files as UTF-8. make sure there are **absolutely no spaces** or text before or after the <?php ?> statements, and make sure you're not echoing out anything but the JSON, as that would make your JSON malformed.

Answer (score 0):

test this

```
$('#numDevices').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var test = [];
        var $number = $('#element');
        var value = $number.val();
        var container = $('#main');
        $('.device').remove();
        $('#send').remove();
        for(var i=0; i<value; i++) {
             container.append('<div class="device"><fieldset><legend>Device' + i + '</legend><textarea class="input"  rows="10">Please enter a hostname, followed by the corresponding links.</textarea></fieldset></div>');

        }
        container.append('<input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="submit"/>');
         $('#send').click(function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();

             var device = new Array();
             $('textarea').each(function(index, area) {
                 var $area = $(area).val();
                 device.push($area);
             });

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "processData.php",
                 data: {input : device},
                 cache: false,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(data) {
                     alert(data[0]);  
                     alert(data[1]);  
                 },
                 error: function() {
                     alert("FAILED");
                 }
             });
         });
    });
```

In php

```
<?php
$data =$_POST['input'];
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: And that would show [object, object], as alerts can't show objects ?

Comment: when i use `var results = JSON.parse(data); alert(results)` it comes back and says "unexpected end of input" error

Comment: try this little cute function instead of alert,  function dump(obj) {
        var out = '';
        for (var i in obj) {
        out += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
    }

    alert(out);        
   }

Comment: also use "POST" instead of "get" it is safer

Comment: also try adding "json" after data :{input : device},

Comment: after testing this, it fails completely with a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` and this is pointing to the `"json,"` syntax

Comment: I changed it "worked on my localhost" also I worked out the php instead of GET do POST Like that $data =$_POST['input'];